# The difference between per person and each person

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

What's the difference between the two?

> 'It costs $50 per person'
>
> 'It costs $50 each person'

Comment: *per* = *for each* --> 'per person' = 'for each', not 'each'. HTH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*It costs $50* needs an *adverbial* modifier if any is considered appropriate.

> It usually costs $50.
>
> It costs $50 Thursdays.
>
> It costs $50 a bottle.

Adverbs, and the rare adverbial objective (noun used adverbially), fit the bill.

More commonly, to-infinitive clauses and especially prepositional phrases will be used:

> It costs $50 to get there.
>
> It costs $50 on the tram.
>
> It costs $50 for a bottle.
>
> It costs $50 per person.
>
> It costs $50 for each person.

But

> */?It costs $50 each person.

would probably not usually be considered acceptable; it would be an adverbial objective usage, with the preposition 'for' dropped from the prepositional phrase, and this often does not give an acceptable-sounding variant. (This particular example may sound more acceptable in the States than in the UK. 'It costs $50 a person' would however be quite acceptable.)

Comment: “*It costs $50 each person” isn't acceptable US usage; perhaps you have your “more acceptable in the States than in the UK” remark backwards?

Comment: No; it would sound unacceptable here. I've come across a few examples of “It costs $x each person” including one or two from the US, but none with pounds. My perception is that prepositions are more readily dropped in the States (He came [on] Tuesday; she taught [at (a)] school; she appealed [against] the sentence; he stayed [at] home.

Answer (score 1):

'Each person' is commonly used as a subject. 
Eg: Each person must pay $50.
But 'per person' is used as an 'object'.
Eg: It costs $50 per person.

"It costs $50 each person" is not correct usage.
"It costs $50 for each person (to go on the trip)"  or rather
"It will cost each person $50 (to go on the trip)".

PS: I am not sure if the terms 'subject', 'object' are correct in the context.